# Jquery - Make this function reusable

Tags: jquery, function

I have these elements - `[.myCheckBox1, .myCheckBox2, ...]`
And these elements - `[.myCheckBoxList1, .myCheckBoxList2, ...]`
How do I make the code pluggable so I don't have to duplicate the bulk?

Ideally what I would like to have is

```
[FUNCTION]

$('.myCheckBox1, .myCheckBox2, etc').[FUNCTION]

$('.myCheckBoxList1, .myCheckBoxList2, etc').[FUNCTION]
```

Code below is what I am wanting to modify:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".myCheckBox1").click(function () {
            $(".myCheckBoxList1").change();
        });
        $(".myCheckBoxList1").change(function () {
            var moneys = 0;
            $(this).find(":checked").each(function () {
                moneys += parseInt($(this).attr('value'));
            });
            $('.OMG').html(moneys.toString());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You should give these elements a common class... it does not seem to make sense to give them classes which look like IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a [jquery plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring), or you could use the same class for all checkboxes (`.myCheckBox`) and the same class for all checkbox lists (`.myChecBoxList`). If you post your html I could give you an example.